# Why does OWASP ZAP not run in Github actions?

Tags: github-actions, owasp

I am trying to run an OWASP ZAP scan using GitHub actions and:

```
name: zapfull-security-scan
on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ dev ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:     
    - name: OWASP ZAP Full Scan
      uses: zaproxy/action-full-scan@v0.4.0
      with:
        target: "mysite.ai/"
```

The build and deploy runs with no errors but no report is produced (nothing in issues tab, nothing in build). What am I missing?

EDIT:
This is in an existing repo so I am guessing the problem is that Github is building that dev repo rather than running this scan maybe? So I try moving this to an empty repo but then no Action run happens. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no `dev` branch, so I chnaged it to `main`!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs :) https://github.com/marketplace/actions/owasp-zap-full-scan

For a start the latest version is currently 0.2.0 not 0.4.0 and secondly the URL needs to start with either `http://` or `https://`